# My code that checks for duplicate isnt working

Tags: python-3.x

Hpwdy, I'm doing a code and the question tells me to write a function sameSet(L1, L2) that checks whether two lists L1 and L2 have
the same elements in some order, ignoring duplicates. For example, the two lists

L1 = [1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11]

and

L2 = [11, 11, 7, 9, 16, 4, 1]

would be considered identical. You will probably need one or more helper functions.

I already worked my own code but it keeps giving me syntax error. Can anyone please help me fix my code? Thanks. Here it is:

```
def sameSet(list1,list2):
    list1 = sorted(set(list1))
    list2 = sorted(set(list2))
if list1.len() == list2.len():
    for i in list1.len():
        if(list1[i] != list2[i]:
return false;
return true
    else
return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple errors.

1. Indentation errors
2. Syntax errors: Use `len(list1)` instead of `list1.len()`, Iterate using `range()` function instead of just an integer object.

   ```
   def sameSet(list1,list2):
       list1 = sorted(set(list1))
       list2 = sorted(set(list2))
       if len(list1) == len(list2):
           for i in range(len(list1)):
               if(list1[i] != list2[i]):
                  return False
           return True
       else:
           return False
   L1 = [1, 4, 9, 16, 9, 7, 4, 9, 11]
   L2 = [11, 11, 7, 9, 16, 4, 1]
   print (sameSet(L1,L2))
   ```

Also, How about converting them into sets and comparing them directly?

```
return set(list1)==set(list2)
```